# Finding Montreal map from 1921?

Tags: canada, 1920s, quebec, maps

Looking for rue Rivet in Montreal around 1921. I am looking to find out where some of my relatives lived in the city. I know it's not too far from where I am currently but cannot find a map. I am assuming the area was destroyed when Radio Canada was built.

Answer (score 1):

I used a Google search on "montreal historic maps" to find **Old maps of Montreal** at http://www.oldmapsonline.org/en/Montreal

On that page I clicked the **Browse the old maps** button and on the right hand side I noticed a Rand McNally map from 1924 that you can click to view.  This only has a few major streets named on it but if you go back a step and look at the Rand McNally map from 1903 that has lots of streets.

I was also able to find Rue Rivet in Google Maps at https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Rue+Rivet,+Montr%C3%A9al-Est,+QC,+Canada/@45.634806,-73.5208797,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4cc8e21b17a32135:0x9989a7ac26c57930!8m2!3d45.634806!4d-73.518691